# How to install the MINI4x6 terminal font on the latest Raspbian (Jessie-lite)

Tags: raspbian, jessie-lite

I'm using a small 3.2" LCD screen and want to get as much text on it as possible (console screen). So far I can choose between Terminus6x12 or VGA8x8, but the MINI4x6 font seems to be missing.

I have figured out that the font should be stored in `/usr/share/consolefonts` but I have not found where I can download any copy (and I'm also not sure if it will be implicitly "installed" if I just copy a file to that location).

Is there any way I can get it installed (other than getting an older Raspbian image)?

Comment: *"I have figured out that the font should be stored in /usr/share/consolefonts"* -> I'm not so sure.  Some console fonts are compiled into the kernel.  However, if it is something that involves a file, and you can figure out the name or a unique element thereof, you could use `apt-file` to search for the package containing it (you will have to install `apt-file` first and read the man page).  Note that jessie-lite uses the same repo as standard jessie, just the base image contains less and is configured a bit differently.

Comment: @goldilocks I installed apt-file and tried `sudo apt-file -v -i search MINI4x6` but without any result at all (verbose, case-insensitive). If it would be compiled into the kernel then I should be able to find its source (or a resource file or something), but a google search on 'MINI4x6' only gets me references to the font from source files (or something that looks like generated documentation). I do see that some guys are recompiling the kernel to get support for their LCD displays but that's a path I'd rather avoid since it is working as-is (except the 4x6 font). Thanks for the hint though.

Comment: It is in the kernel source: `[src]/lib/fonts/font_mini_4x6.c` includes a reference to "MINI4x6".